# How to create a function for a dynamic pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have created a pickerview that opens up after tapping a textfield in my screen. Looking at the code for the pickerview you can see it only has two inputs: the textfield outlet to which it should belong, and an array that populates the pickerview. It also has a nice toolbar that saves the input or lets you go to the next input field.

In the code below you can see how I set it up.

```
class PersonalDetails: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerTextFieldCountry: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pickOptionCountry = ["Belgium", "France", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Sweden"]

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "nextPicker")
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton, spaceButton, nextButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    pickerTextFieldCountry.inputView = pickerView
    pickerTextFieldCountry.placeholder = "Not Set"
    pickerTextFieldCountry.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    if let text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("test") {pickerTextFieldCountry.text = text}
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}


// MARK - PART TWO: HOW TO INTEGRATE THE FUNCTIONS BELOW?
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickOptionCountry.count}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickOptionCountry[row]}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerTextFieldCountry.text = pickOptionCountry[row]}
func nextPicker() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(pickerTextFieldCountry.text, forKey: "test")
    pickerTextFieldCountry.nextResponder()}
func donePicker() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(pickerTextFieldCountry.text, forKey: "test")
    pickerTextFieldCountry.resignFirstResponder()}
```

Since I'm planning to make ~20 more of the same input fields, I'm looking to make a dynamic function so I do not have to rewrite the same code again and again. Preferably I should be able to call the function via func(textfieldID,arrayID). I'm getting stuck when trying to incorporate the pickerView functions after didReceiveMemoryWarning (see MARK - PART TWO).

Comment: 1 issue is putting everything in `viewDidLoad`, including the data "model" listing the countries, which is a local variable scoped to that method & not available elsewhere. Look into the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern and how to organize your code to separate and encapsulate the UI portions, the UIPickerView creation/delegate methods, and the data you use to populate the pickers. Also, is 20+ pickers the only/best UI for what you need? I'd find that much scrolling of dials to be annoying - wouldn't you? Perhaps drilling down into tableviews, or cards w/radio buttons, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what those functions are for. You can show any type of data using them by writing the logic directly in the picker. For example you can do the following for `numberOfRowsInComponent`:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   switch aVariableIdentifyingTheFiledPressed {
    case 0:
      return pickOptionCountry.count
    case 1:
      return anotherOption.count
   }
}
```

You can even leverage the power of swift and create an enum with all your options

```
enum Planet {
   case optionCountry, anotherOption
}
```

Then build the switch on the enum. Even cooler you can directly put your choices for each option in the enum as raw values!

Comment: Thanks for helping out. What would you say is the best way to set up a variable for identifying the text field pressed?

Comment: If I were you, I would use UIButtons not UILabels. Then one way to get you started until you become more sophisticated would be to put a number in for the tag of the UIButton in storyboard. Then you can do `aVariableIdentifyingTheFiledPressed = sender.tag` in your IBAction.